# Accessing Session after a call to Response.End()

Tags: asp.net

I have a custom http module which does some post processing on a request. This processing runs during the PostRequestHandlerExecute event, and it modifies the SessionState.

I have a third party control which is implementing what their own Callback mechanism. Essentially the component is rendering some XML to the buffer in the Render event of the control after which it calls Response.End().

Because it calls Response.End() none of the other events in the pipeline are being fired. I'm trying to figure out a way to still get my custom module to run this post processing code. I can hook into the EndRequest event but at this point, the Session is no longer available.

**Edit**
Specifically what I need to do is modify the value of two specific slots in session state. One is a value type, and one is a reference type. I am also using InProcess Session State
Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All though `Response.End` (will suggest to use [HttpApplication.CompleteRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.completerequest.aspx) instead) short-circuits application events, session state module will still persists the session state on end request. Whenever session state module persist the session state, it will remove the session bag from the context.

So one of the hack way of doing it could be to have flag in your module. Set the flag if `PostRequestHandlerExecute` is fired. Handle `EndRequest` and if flag is not set then go for session state manipulation. In order to get the session state, clear all modules in your web.config and put your module before session state module (going by general observation that modules receive app events in the order of registration).

Cleaner way would be to have your [own session state store provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178587.aspx) - so that you can expose methods to get the session state bag based on the session id which will be used in your module to manipulate the session slots.

Comment: I like the idea of having my own session state provider, for my actual problem I resolved this by handling the processing on the next request. (I'm basically changing the context of the user, and need to undo the change so I check to see if the context is left in the modified state). But I do like the idea of rolling my own provider